# vue pagination total didn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

```
<template>
  ...
  <div class="pagination">
     <el-pagination
        @current-change="handleCurrentChange"
        layout="prev, pager, next"
        :total="totalCount">
     </el-pagination>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    Vue.use(ElementUI);
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tableData: [],
                orderTableUrl: setting.orderTableUrl,
                width: 110,
                page_size: 10,
                page_num: 1,
                messages: [],
                totalCount: 100,
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getTableData()
        },
        methods: {
            getTableData: function () {
                let self = this;
                axios.Get({
                    url: self.orderTableUrl,
                    params: {
                        'page_size': self.page_size,
                        'page_num': self.page_num
                    },
                    callback: function (res) {
                        self.tableData = res.data.orders;
                        self.totalCount = res.data.orders_total_pages;
                        console.log(self.totalCount)
                    }
                });
            },
      }    
}
```

the pagination part use `element.ui` .
Here is my problem: in method callback, console.log can echo real num of total page, but it cannot display on template, and only can see the num 1 of page on window.
I'm so puzzled for that.
Is it said that vue can immediately show data on change on view

Comment: Your code should work. You can try `Vue.set(self, 'tableData', res.data.orders);` instead of `self.tableData = res.data.orders;` just for the sake of it...

Comment: thanks for your answer. the 'tableData' is for table data. it can works.  'totalCount' also can seen it changes eventually. But i am puzzled why it cannot show on template

Comment: Well... you are not using it anywhere in the template you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

finish the question. the ':total' does work, just surprised that it means the count of objects instead of pages ...